# Post multiple data using Jquery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this script below that sends only 1 value to the requested URL, but now I need to adjust it to accept 2, I couldn't find a way to do that.

Each checkbox is accompanied by an input hidden named #note, I need to pass this #note value (that's my order ID) together.

```
$('#importaNF').click(function(){
 var checkbox = $('.import_checkbox:checked');
 if(checkbox.length > 0)
 {
  var checkbox_value = [];
  $(checkbox).each(function(){
   checkbox_value.push($(this).val());
  });
  $.ajax({
   url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>adm/pedidos/importaNF",
   method:"POST",
   data:{checkbox_value:checkbox_value},
   success:function()
   {
    $('.removeRow').fadeOut(1500);
   }
  })
 }
 else
 {
  alert('Select atleast one records');
 }
}
```

My HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="import_checkbox" name="import_checkbox" value="<?= $registro->NUMERO ?>">
    <input type="input" id="note" class="import_input" name="import_input" value="<?= $registro->FATURA ?>" style="visibility:hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: what is your html looks like?

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML as well ?

Comment: I have updated my question with HTML

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpretting, but you can just extract it like you did the checkbox value and add a second property to the data object:

```
data:{checkbox_value:checkbox_value, note_value: note_value},
```

Unless you mean you're trying to pass a second url parameter?